# Geometry nodes: how do I make spikes that have a little bit of curves to them on a curved surface?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to make short spikey hair and I want the hairs to have a bit of variation to them. If the spikes were facing upward I could just offset the x and y values, but this is supposed to be on a head and I don't understand how I would do this on a curved surface.